# Deleting multiple lines from a csv file using sed

Tags: unix, csv, sed

I am just learning to work with csv files from the command line. I want to delete several lines from a file using `sed`. I've removed the header of a file with this `cat file.csv | sed 1,2d > file.csv`.

Now I want to delete several more lines from the file (lines 3, 10, 12, and 28-35) and I am not sure how to pull it off. I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the sed implementation, you could separate them as follows:

```
cat file.csv | sed "1,2d;10d;12d;28,35d" > file2.csv
```

Comment: I'm getting errors: `-bash: 10d: command not found` and the same for `12d` and `28,35d`. As with before, `1,2d` is working. Is it possible that the structure of the csv is to blame?

Comment: The file would not be the cause. My example must not be valid in all cases. I was running it on Windows with what may likely be a version of sed not fully compatible. I'll have to test it more tomorrow. Sorry for the bad lead.

Comment: Some seds don't implement the semi-colon. Use the `-e` flag several times.

Comment: @Jeff: It probably is not an improvement over just using multiple commands via `-e`, but quoting the script appears to make it work.

Comment: If you get an error from bash it's probably because you forgot to use the quotation marks - it thinks ";" starts a new command and tries to run the 10d command.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-e` flag to pass several commands to one `sed` invocation, like this:

```
seq 1 40 | sed -e 1,2d -e 3d -e 10d -e 12d -e 28,35d
```